# Adding z column for z values from draped raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, drape

I'm trying to use the drape set z value to raster function in QGIS. I have a shapefile of points with the coordinates x and y and a DEM raster. I would like to give the z value to the points by taking it from the raster. When I apply the drape function, it generates a new shp file but without any new z field.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drape does not add a column with Z values, it sets the actual Z value of the geometry. (Like the points can have x and y coordinates without having x and y columns)

Use Extract Z values to add a column:

> Extracts z values from geometries into feature attributes. By default
>   only the z value from the first vertex of each feature is extracted,
>   however the algorithm can optionally calculate statistics on all of
>   the geometry's z values, including sums, means, and minimums and
>   maximums

[image]

Or field calculator:

```
z( $geometry )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have Extract Z values en Qgis 3.4, so I'll  download another version and I'll try again. Thank you Bera.

Comment: Oh it works!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to extract the Z data from your DEM and add it to a new field in the point layer you can use the Field Calculator.

In the point layer's Attribute Table,open the  Field Calculator, select create a new field (numeric, real) and use this expression:

```
raster_value ('DEM', 1, $geometry)
```

Change DEM with the name of your raster.

This will create a new field with the elevation extracts from your DEM.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Val P!