# Draw automated perpendicular profiles on lines at 800m distance on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have the DEM of the area I'm working in. I have geological faults as lines.
I now want to create perpendicular topographic profiles to the faults at 800m distance.

Comment: You'd have to split the line at distance then draw a perpendicular line https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380361/creating-perpendicular-lines-on-line-using-qgis, then to add topographic information to the transect https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357624/adding-z-column-for-z-values-from-draped-raster-using-qgis which should give your transects values from a raster DEM. Hope that helps.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here should not only state the task but also describe what you have attempted, and where you are stuck.